# WooCommerce orders list: Calculate Totals based on filtered results

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders

Is there a way to get total amount from all orders in Orders list (in admin), based on filtered results (For example total sum of all orders in February month).

[image: Orders list example]

Any ideas how to handle this?